# Android's LinearLayout for Swing

Tags: java, android, swing, android-linearlayout, layout-manager

Is there a LayoutManager for Swing that acts as LinearLayout in Android? I like an idea of components weights very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need individual weights use GridBagLayout. Or you can try BoxLayout.

Comment: It seems GridBagLayout is close enough to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the FlowLayout, GridLayout or BorderLayout. In my experience in building GUI in java, I mostly use combinations of BorderLayouts (most of the time) and GridLayouts.

[Layout Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

If you want it to look like

[image]

the code is:

```
public void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(0, 1));

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");
    add(jButton1);

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");
    add(jButton2);

    jButton3.setText("jButton3");
    add(jButton3);

    jButton4.setText("jButton4");
    add(jButton4);
}
```

Comment: I don't want components to have equal sizes as it happens with GridLayout. I want them to be proportional to its individual layout weights like in Android's LinearLayout.

Comment: Then the answer is use FlowLayout. But the problem with flow is that when you maximize your window, all components are rearrange.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SwanLayout https://github.com/idayrus/swan-layout

This library bring **LinearLayout** and **FrameLayout** implementation to Java Swing

Example in kotlin:

```kotlin
val panelVertical = JPanel(LinearLayout(LinearLayout.VERTICAL))
val panelHorizontal = JPanel(LinearLayout(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL))
val lc = LinearConstraints()

lc.reset()
lc.width = 0
lc.weight = 0.5
lc.margin = 10
lc.marginEnd = 5
panelHorizontal.add(JButton("Horizontal (weight 0.5)"), lc)

lc.reset()
lc.width = 0
lc.weight = 0.5
lc.margin = 10
lc.marginStart = 5
panelHorizontal.add(JButton("Horizontal (weight 0.5)"), lc)

// Add panelHorizontal to panelVertical
lc.reset()
lc.width = LinearConstraints.MATCH_PARENT
lc.height = LinearConstraints.WRAP_CONTENT
panelVertical.add(panelHorizontal, lc)

lc.reset()
lc.margin = 10
lc.marginTop = 0
lc.width = LinearConstraints.WRAP_CONTENT
lc.height = LinearConstraints.WRAP_CONTENT
lc.gravity = LinearConstraints.CENTER
panelVertical.add(JButton("Gravity Center"), lc)

lc.reset()
lc.margin = 10
lc.marginTop = 0
lc.width = LinearConstraints.MATCH_PARENT
lc.height = LinearConstraints.MATCH_PARENT
panelVertical.add(JButton("Fill Remain"), lc)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYpEb.png)