# Android's LinearLayout equivalent in Swing

Tags: java, swing, android-linearlayout

I have seen this thread which asked the exact same question I have now, but find the answers a bit unsatisfactory:

[Android's LinearLayout for Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9409498/androids-linearlayout-for-swing/23627385?noredirect=1#comment36279088_23627385)

I created a class WeightedPanel like so:

```
public class WeightedPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6844740568601141924L;
private boolean mVertical;
private double mLastWeight = 1;
private GridBagConstraints mConstraints;
private int mLastGrid = 0;

public WeightedPanel(boolean vertical) {
    mVertical = vertical;
    mConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();

    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
}

@Override
public Component add(Component comp) {
    return add(comp, mLastWeight);
}

public Component add(Component comp, double weight) {
    if (mVertical) {
        mConstraints.weighty = weight;
        mConstraints.weightx = 1;
        mConstraints.gridy = mLastGrid;
        mConstraints.gridx = 0;
    } else {
        mConstraints.weightx = weight;
        mConstraints.weighty = 1;
        mConstraints.gridx = mLastGrid;
        mConstraints.gridy = 0;
    }
    mConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

    add(comp, mConstraints);

    mLastWeight = weight;
    mLastGrid += weight;
    return comp;
}

public Component add(Component comp, int weight) {
    return add(comp, (double) weight);
}
```

}

This kind of works, but I have two problems with it:

1) In my application, I have a login screen:

```
@Override
protected void addComponents(WeightedPanel jPanel) {
    mUpdateListener = new UpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUpdate() {
            LoginFrame.this.onUpdate();
        }
    };
    WeightedPanel panel = getUserPanel();
    jPanel.add(panel);

    panel = getPasswordPanel();
    jPanel.add(panel);

    mLoginButton = getLoginButton();
    jPanel.add(mLoginButton);
}

private WeightedPanel getPasswordPanel() {
    WeightedPanel result = new WeightedPanel(false);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Password");
    result.add(label);

    mPasswordField = new PasswordField(mUpdateListener);
    result.add(mPasswordField);
    return result;
}

private WeightedPanel getUserPanel() {
    WeightedPanel result = new WeightedPanel(false);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("User");
    result.add(label);

    mUserTextField = new TextField(mUpdateListener);
    result.add(mUserTextField);
    return result;
}
```

which in practice looks like this:

[Click to view](http://workupload.com/file/EGx60lMl)

Why aren't the labels and text fields all the same size here? I figure it's got something to do with the fact that "Password" is a longer string than "User", but that's obviously not what I want!

2) My second problem is this. I have another screen like so:

```
@Override
protected void addComponents(WeightedPanel jPanel) {

    WeightedPanel scrollPanePanel = getOrdersScrollPane();
    jPanel.add(scrollPanePanel);

    WeightedPanel buttonPanel = getButtonPanel();
    jPanel.add(buttonPanel);
}

private WeightedPanel getOrdersScrollPane() {
    WeightedPanel result = new WeightedPanel(true);

    JPanel filterPanel = getFilterPanel();
    result.add(filterPanel, 1);

    mTableModel = new OrdersTableModel();
    mTable = new JTable(mTableModel);
    mTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    mTable.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
            checkEnabled();
        }
    });
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mTable);

    result.add(scrollPane, 40);

    return result;
}
```

It really doesn't look bad in practice:

[Click to view](http://workupload.com/file/JmKXYLcL)

But have a look at the getOrdersScrollPane() function. The call to functions result.add(filterPanel, 1); and result.add(scrollPane, 50); say that the proportion between the filter panel and the scroll pane should be 1:50, but looking at the scroll pane, it's definitely not 50 times the size of the filter panel. Obviously, I am exaggerating to make my point, I don't really want a proportion of 1:50; it just strikes me that it makes no difference whether I do result.add(scrollPane, 10); or result.add(scrollPane, 50);

Comment: Yeah, I could copy-paste the some 10 lines of code from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) to do this. But maybe you can first post what you have tried?

Comment: I did have a look at the GridBagConstraints but it didn't work out. I find the parameters rather confusing. The simple example I am requesting is not contained in that tutorial...

Comment: Gridx and Gridy so set the location in the grid, Fill to set how the buttons stretch and weightx to set how much width each one takes up. Really, at least show us you made an attempt and try to debug what didn't work.

Comment: I did make an attempt a few days ago and didn't get it done, probably because I was erratically trying out different layout managers without really being sure which one I should use. I only thought someone might have a quick anwer for me so I don't have to read my way through all of these fancy features each layout manager has, but which I just don't need. At least it seems like GridBagLayout really is what I need, I'll try out again tonight and see if it works..

Comment: Please do, if you still have problems tomorrow - edit the question with where you got and what you're stuck with

Comment: Doesn't anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: Not at that time of day, no :) Anyway, you should post a comment when updating a question, since otherwise we will not get a notification. Will look into the problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both questions stem from an incorrect understanding of GridBagLayout. A bit more reading and experimenting should help) To answer the question at hand:

1)  The problem here is that you want a single GridBagLayout, but instead are adding 2 independent panels.
The result: The columns in the top grid bag are independent of the columns in the bottom grid bag.
To rectify this, there are 2 things you can try:

1. Add both labels and both text fields to a single GridBag panel. That way the columns will align.
2. Make a minimum and preferred size for the labels so that their width matches and set their weightx to 0 (and weightx of text fields non-zero). That way you are making the GridBags allocate the same amount of space for the labels and text fields.

The first method is preferred, but not always possible. The second method is hacky and *will likely break* as soon as you change the label string, a user set a different default font etc, etc.

2) Here you are misunderstanding what weighty does.
It does **not** make your components of the specified proportion. That should be clear enough since you can mix 0 and non-0 weight components in a single layout.
What it does, is it allocates the preferred (or minimum) sizes for components, and distributes the *remaining* space in that proportion. Which means if you make your panel 100 pixels higher by resizing the window, 2 will go to the top panel adding spacing, and 98 will go to the table.
What you likely wanted is to make the weighty of the top filter 0 (so that there is no awkward spacings in large windows) and control its actual height with setPreferred and setMinimum size (or by setting those on the embedded components).

**EDIT**

As docs for Linear Layout state, to achieve a fixed proportion of sizes of components (the initial problem), one has to set their preferred sizes to 0, and then set weights (then all space is remaining space, and is distributed according to weights only). This also works for the GridBag variant.

Comment: But now we're back at my initial question: With my "WeightedPanel" class I am trying to implement the exact behaviour of Android's LinearLayout with Swing: A panel that - when added as the only component of a frame - consumes the entire space available in that frame. The only panel parameter should be "Horizontal" or "Vertical". Then, each component added to that panel will be stacked horizontally or vertically, with the weight argument specifying the amount of space this component is to consume in proportion to all other components added to that panel.

Comment: @user805623 That is NOT how linear layout works. [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html) clearly state that, as in GridBag, **remaining** space is distributed according to weights.

Comment: @user805623 If you are referring to the extra little thing on the right that explains how to make equally sized children, then the trick works here as well: Set the individual component sizes to 0, then add them to the grid bag. Then they will be sized according to weights only.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right and I vaguely remember I had the same kind of problem with linear layout at the start when I tried to achieve this behaviour: Set each component's size to 0px. I'll try out tonight...

Comment: @user805623 Great, care to accept the answer if it helped you?